# Sending System.out to console in Java

Tags: java, jar, console

How do you make it so that your executable jar opens and sends all `System.out.println()` to a command prompt? When I export and open the jar I don't see anything happen.

Double clicking to open the jar.

Comment: Open the jar from the command line?

Comment: execute the jar in cmd, sopln() statements will be displayed on cmd

Comment: are you talking about self executable jar?

Comment: yeah self executable

Answer (score 0):

You would have to open the jar in the command line to be able to view it's System.out() commands.

You can usually do so with "  java -jar 'JarName'.jar " Without quotes and substituting the name of you jar file.